# Windows 10: How do you mix START program.exe /max AND COLOR "XX" commands to RUN an exe with different foreground/background colors in one .bat file?

Tags: batch-file, colors, windows-10, maximize

I'm trying to do this without opening two windows. I've looked up both commands and tried every combination I can come up with. In every case the program either opens the .exe and changes the colors (but doesn't maximize) or it opens maximized but does not apply the color command.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and/or risk a look into Jon Skeet's [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). You are always welcome to ask, but please provide examples and keep the above in mind. :)

Comment: `start "window title" /max cmd /c "color XX & program.exe"`

Comment: Showing us the combinations you've tried would certainly help with minimise repeated attempts to help you.

Comment: Thank you eryksun. Worked perfectly. Sorry Fatalbullethit, the only other info I could've added was: Start /max /b color 4A & program.exe. (every combination of those switches possible)<-- those were the only switches I found in my 2 hr search on StackOverflow. I did not see a /c switch but I've researched it now and have become .00001% smarter! Eryksun had no problem understanding the question. Thanks again sir!

Comment: By default CMD's `start` command runs a single internal command or external program. If you need to run a complex command line with a sequence of commands or pipes, then the single command to run has to be cmd.exe itself, with the `/c` option to run the given command line, which should be quoted in general. If you want this new shell to continue running after the command is finished, use `/k` instead of `/c`.